# Get value from key/value pair using jmespath when value is a number

Tags: python, jmespath

I am trying to retrieve the key (instanceId) from a JSON document using jmespath.  The JSON documents looks like this:

```
targets = {'instances':
  [
     {'instanceId': u'i-035dd764fe1a08091', 'hostIp': '10.200.10.150'}, 
     {'instanceId': u'i-04ed0d110fef5aef7', 'hostIp': '10.200.10.121'}, 
     {'instanceId': u'i-0f7778162b14c954f', 'hostIp': '10.200.20.135'}
  ]
}
```

I feel like this should work:

`jmespath.search('instances[?hostIp=="10.200.10.150"].instanceId', targets)`

but it returns an empty set.  When replace the IP address with a string, e.g. a letter, it returns the instanceId. What is the jmespath syntax for searching for a value when it is a number?  Ultimately, I'm trying to get the instanceId from the hostIp.

Answer (score 1):

`hostIp=="10.200.10.150"` compares the value of hostIp in the object with the value of 10.200.10.150 in the object (i.e. uses the IP as a key, not a raw value). If you want it to be a raw value, you need to either use single quotes, or use backquotes to start raw json (and then use `` `"10.200.10.150"` ``)

Answer (score -1):

For some reason python implementation requires *`* (backtick) text delimiter instead of *`'`* or *`"`*

So this returns empty list:

`In [1]: jp.search('instances[?hostIp=="10.200.10.150"].instanceId', targets)
Out[1]: []`

But this returns what You are looking for:

`` In [2]: jp.search('instances[?hostIp==`10.200.10.150`].instanceId', targets)
Out[2]: ['i-035dd764fe1a08091'] ``

Comment: The python jmespath implementation appears to behave outside spec here, falling back to interpreting backquoted things as strings when they don't parse as JSON. This will not work, e.g., in the go jmespath implementation, and is in general not a reliable way to get a raw string value (because if it's valid JSON, then...).

See my other answer for the spec-compliant ways to compare with raw string values.